# How to promote and demote users group with whatsapp-web.js

Tags: node.js, backend, chatbot, whatsapp

Most of the other commands I managed to run fine, but to promote users or downgrade I can't find it, if anyone knows tell me there

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```js
const chat = await client.getChatById("0000000000@g.us"); // Group Id
await chat.promoteParticipants(["0000000000@c.us"]); // User Id
await chat.demoteParticipants(["0000000000@c.us"]); // User Id
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).